# How to model references in an ontology

Tags: graphs, database-theory, modelling, ontologies

I am interested in creating an ontology which will model arguments (among other things). For example, a triple in the ontology might be

`Vaccination -> can lead to -> Autism`

(not that I necessarily believe this, just a good example of an argument).
I would like to attach sources to any disputed statement. So ideally, the above example would be stored as

`Vaccination -> can lead to -> Autism -> according to -> Article X`

This cannot easily be represented as a triple in a standard ontology. What are the accepted ways of modeling this type of data?

I see that on WikiData, all relations can have sources attached to them (e.g. see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q23 for sources on when George Washington was born). It could be that WikiData doesn't store their data as triples.

Comment: For that particular 'argument', you'd want to attach a large number of references contradicting it. Then usual normalisation of the design would say to use an auxiliary relation to record supporting and contradicting evidence/sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to say something about an RDF triple (i.e., an `rdf:Statement`), you can use [**reification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-mt-20140225/#reification):

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix voc: <https://example.com/vocabulary#> .
@prefix :    <https://example.com/instances#> .

:Triple42   rdf:type        rdf:Statement .
:Triple42   rdf:subject     :Vaccination . 
:Triple42   rdf:predicate   voc:canLeadTo . 
:Triple42   rdf:object      :Autism .
:Triple42   voc:publishedIn <https://example.com/articles/vaccination-and-autism> .
```

But you would probably want to say something about the argument, not about the RDF statement expressing the argument. You can use [**n-ary relations**](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) for this, e.g., by introducing an instance that represents the argument:

```
@prefix voc: <https://example.com/vocabulary#> .
@prefix :    <https://example.com/instances#> .

:Argument1 a voc:Argument .
:Argument1 voc:publishedIn <https://example.com/articles/vaccination-and-autism> .
:Argument1 voc:textualRepresentation "Vaccination can lead to autism!" .
```

(and then use properties that dissect the argument to represent it in a machine-readable way)

---

Relevant vocabularies: [PROV](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-overview/), [`schema:ClaimReview`](https://schema.org/ClaimReview)

Comment: The second part of your answer helps me with this problem. Thanks!